# Reading a binary file from a GUI

Tags: java, binary

Why isn't the panel loading. I am unable to tell if it's saving correctly either.

```
public void saveParks(JPanel parkingPanel) throws IOException
    {
        //save parkingPanel JPanel that contains the two car parks
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("saveParkPanel.dat"));

        output.writeObject(parkingPanel);
        System.out.println("saved");
        output.close();
    }

    public void loadParks() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("saveParkPanel.dat"));

        JPanel parkingPanel = (JPanel)input.readObject();
        System.out.println("loaded");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't the panel loading.

Because you don't add it in a `JWindow` or a `JFrame`.
Loading a `JPanel` instance you have previously serialized is not enough to display it.

Try something like :

```
 JPanel parkingPanel = (JPanel)input.readObject();
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.add(parkingPanel);
```

> I am unable to tell if it's saving correctly either.

If you have not any `NotSerializableException` during the serialization, it is rather good sign.

Comment: The class is a JPanel constructor, it extends JPanel.

Comment: Yes but to display it you have to add it in a `RootPaneContainer` such as JFrame.

Comment: Tried that and I'm getting  Erroneous sym type: CarPark.AddVehiclePanel.loadParks
Where I try and call the method. It said I need a JFrame argument but when I put loadParks(frame) of course frame is out of scope.

Comment: Why not  change loadParks() so that it returns the deserialized `JPanel` instead of `void`?